# Powershell regex in variable

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm busy making a PS script that moves files to new or existing folder based on numbers in the file name. 
Now I have a PS script, I have the regex needed but I can't figure out how to put the regex result in the variable.

**PS script:**

```
$root = "\\fqdn\share"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root

ForEach ($file in $files)
{
    $year = $file.regexfilter
    $month = $file.regexfilter
    $dir_path = Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath $year
    $dir_path_month = Join-Path $dir_path -ChildPath $month
    $letters = $file.BaseName[0..2] -join ""
    $dir_sub_full = Join-Path -Path $dir_path_month -ChildPath $letters
    If (!(Test-Path $dir_path)) {

        New-Item -Path $root -Name $year -ItemType Directory

    }
    If (!(Test-Path $dir_path_month))
    {
        New-Item -Path $root\$year\ -Name $month -ItemType Directory
    }
    If (!(Test-Path $dir_sub_full))
    {
        New-Item -Path $root\$year\$month -Name $letters -ItemType Directory
    }
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $dir_sub_full
 }
```

The filenames in question are `blablabla_11709220290`, where number 2 and 3 are the year & numbers 4 & 5 the month.

So the regex I have is:

Year: `.*_\d\d\d(\d{2})\d*`

Month: `.*_\d\d\(\d{2})\d*`

Now I need the result of that regex in the variable `$year` and `$month`.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you can do that without regex. Use `($file -split "_")]1].Substring(...)` to extract the name pieces you want. Using a `-Filter` argument to `Get-ChildItem` would also be a good idea.

Comment: @Tomalak minor nit pick `-split` is still a regex operator so you would need to be cognizant of special characters. `"".Split()` would work just as well in this case without that caveat

Comment: @Matt You're right. It won't do any harm here, but I actually did not think of it myself when I wrote the comment.

Comment: `$file.BaseName[0..2] -join ""` -> `$file.BaseName.Substring(0,3)` should be simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is what you want to do:

```
$root = '\\fqdn\share'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -File

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $match = $file.BaseName -match '.*_(?<year>\d{2})(?<month>\d{2}).*'    
    if (-not $match) {
        Write-Warning "Could not extract year/month from: $file"
        continue
    }    
    $letters = $file.BaseName[0..2] -join ""
    $subdir = [IO.Path]::Combine($root, $matches.year, $matches.month, $letters)
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $subdir)) {
        New-Item -Path $subdir -ItemType Directory > $null
    }
    $newfile = Join-Path -Path $subdir -ChildPath $file.Name
    if (Test-Path -Path $newfile) {
        Write-Warning "File $($file.Name) already exists in: $subdir"
        continue
    }
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $subdir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this with pure regex you could use [named groups](http://tasteofpowershell.blogspot.ca/2012/01/named-groups-in-regular-expressions.html) to get your variables where you want them. If you have the means to isolate the files you want you can perform this test on the resulting `$file.BaseName`

```
[void]("blablabla_11709220290" -match "_\d(?<year>\d{2})(?<month>\d{2})")
$Matches.year
$Matches.month
```

So using `-match` with named groups we get the characters you want exactly where you want them.

This can easily be applied as a pipeline filter in a where clause

```
Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object{$_.BaseName -match "_\d(?<year>\d{2})(?<month>\d{2})"} | ForEach-Object{
    write-host $_.BaseName
    $Matches.year
    $Matches.month
}
```

---

As [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) points out you don't *need* to use regex here as you know the positions of your characters.

```
$null,$split = "blablabla_11709220290".split("_") 
$year = $split.substring(1,2)
$month = $split.substring(3,2)
```

Split the string on the underscore. Dispose of the result before the delimeter and capture the rest into a variable. In this case `$split` will be a string but if there are multiple underscores then it would be an array.

Then just take substrings where you expect to find you year and month.

Comment: I didn't know the "-match" extension. That solved everything, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Correct, with a small modification that is indeed the way to use it:

```
$root = '\\fqdn\path'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -File

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $match = $file.BaseName -match '.*_\d(?<year>\d{2})(?<month>\d{2}).*'    
    if (-not $match) {
        Write-Warning "Could not extract year/month from: $file"
        continue
    }    
      $subdir = [IO.Path]::Combine($root, $matches.year, $matches.month)
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $subdir)) {
        New-Item -Path $subdir -ItemType Directory > $null
    }
    $newfile = Join-Path -Path $subdir -ChildPath $file.Name
    if (Test-Path -Path $newfile) {
        Write-Warning "File $($file.Name) already exists in: $subdir"
        continue
    }
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $subdir
}
```

I want to thank you all for the great support and help on this!